# Node.js Asynchronous Recursive Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, callback

I have a recursive function in Node.js that depends on the return value of its recursive calls that may happen at various spots. It works for smaller test cases, but once I get to my larger data sets, asynchronicity messes it up.

I've tried using a callback and checking if the amount of iterations it hits matches the length of the data set, but it stops before iterating through it all for some reason (memory issue possibly?)

Here's the general flow of the code, so far, with sporadic calls to callback:

```
function recursiveCall(value, array, callback) {
    callback(value)
    if (/*base case*/) {
        return value;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (/*conditional*/) {
            var x = /* work + */ value 
            return recursiveCall(x, array, callback);
        }

        .
        .
        .

        if (/*conditional*/) {
            var x = /* work + */ value
            return recursiveCall(x, array, callback);
        }
    }
}

var iters = 0;
var finalValue = recursiveCall(initialValue, array, function(value) {
     if (++iters >= array.length)
         console.log(value);
});
```

I understand that the value of finalValue will be undefined, but it's a part of the original implementation that worked with the smaller test case.

I just need to be able to log the value at the end.

Thank you so much for the help! It is very much appreciated!

Comment: What part of this is asynchronous? It seems to be entirely synchronous.

Comment: Your callback isn't recursive. It is just an anonymous function called with each recursive iteration of `recursiveCall`. Your recursive invocations seem to be in tail position. I don't know if node.js or the underlying chrome engine already supports TCO. Maybe it's an stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

This is not asynchronous flow. You are using for loop inside recursiveCall function. Alternate of for loop to make loop asynchronous is **forloop** a npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/forloop.

Or you may use

`setInterval(recursiveCall(x, array, callback));`

instead of

`return recursiveCall(x, array, callback);` 
without for loop.